# Add relativelayout programmatically

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have the following XML:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rlDateOne"
        android:background="@drawable/dateborder"
        android:padding="@dimen/date_layout_pad" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/cal_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cal_icon_size"
            android:src="@drawable/calicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:text="@string/date_one"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cal_text_left_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/cal_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/dateholiday" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDate"
            android:text="@string/holiday_one"
            android:textSize="@dimen/cal_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/dateholiday" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
        android:src="@drawable/divider" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rlDateOne"
        android:background="@drawable/dateborder"
        android:padding="@dimen/date_layout_pad" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/cal_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cal_icon_size"
            android:src="@drawable/calicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:text="@string/date_two"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cal_text_left_margin"

            android:textSize="@dimen/cal_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/dateholiday" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDate"
            android:text="@string/holiday_two"
            android:textSize="@dimen/cal_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/dateholiday" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivCal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/divider_height"
        android:src="@drawable/divider" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rlDateOne"
        android:background="@drawable/dateborder"
        android:padding="@dimen/date_layout_pad" >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/cal_icon_size"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/cal_icon_size"
            android:src="@drawable/calicon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:text="@string/date_three"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cal_text_left_margin"
            android:textSize="@dimen/cal_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/dateholiday" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReason"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ivIcon"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvDate"
            android:text="@string/holiday_three"
            android:textSize="@dimen/cal_text_size"
            android:textColor="@color/dateholiday" />

    </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

As you can see above, there is a repeat of the same code (From `ImageView` to `</RelativeLayout>` and this is just an example. I have to repeat it 41 times, instead of 3 that is shown here.

- Instead of using XML how do I add it programmatically (Let's say `tvDate` and `tvReason` are String arrays)?
- Is it recommended to just use XML or add it in Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make separated xml file and inflate views (any quantity) when ever you need:

```
...
public void onCreate(Bundle b){
super(b);
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
...

View yourView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_xml_file, null);
yourBasicLayout.addView(yourView);
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a ListView where every item has the repeating layout. In that way you can repeat it as many times as you like.

Comment: It does not necessarily have to be a ListView.